# gradle - cleanup after task complete with dependsOn

Tags: gradle

I have two custom tasks like --

```
task taskA(type: SomeTaskA) {
    ....
}
task taskB(type: SomeTaskB, dependsOn: 'taskA') {
    ....
}
```

taskA generates a file and performs some operations on it.
taskB also performs some operations on the file that is generated by taskA.
I can run both the tasks individually.

I need to delete this file when gradle command complete, ie., if I run gradle taskA then the file will delete when taskA completed and if I run gradle taskB then the file will delete when taskB completed.

I can achieve first part by adding doLast block and add delete logic there but when I run taskB then I have no file to perform operation (because taskA doLast already deleted the file).

Is then anyway to stop taskA doLast when I run taskB, or any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a dedicated "cleanup" task to handle the file deletion, and make both tasks `taskA` and `taskB` be ***finalized by*** this task `cleanup`:

```
task cleanup{
    doLast{
        // DELETE the file
    }
}

taskA.finalizedBy cleanup
taskB.finalizedBy cleanup
```

This way, the file will always be deleted, either you run taks A or B. And this will ensure that `taskB` is executed before the file is deleted by task  `cleanup` as well.

Comment: Thank you for this quick answer. Working awesome.